# Крестики-нолики js

Tags: javascript, html, css, разработка-игр

делал крестики-нолики на js, но встретил ошибки. 1 ошибка - *Uncaught TypeError: document.getElementById(...) is null строки - 40:14*. 2 ошибка - *undefinedscript.js строки - 37:6*. Я в js начинающий, поэтому прошу простить за глупость, заранее спасибо. Вот код:

```js
let play = true;
let argument;
let map = Array(9); //Поле
let x = []; //Клетки, которые занял крестик
let o = []; //Клетки, которые занял нолик
//победные комбинации
let winner = [
  //по горизонтали
  [0, 1, 2],
  [3, 4, 5],
  [6, 7, 8],
  //по вертикали
  [0, 3, 6],
  [1, 4, 7],
  [2, 5, 8],
  //по диагонали
  [0, 4, 8],
  [2, 5, 6],
];
//------------------------------------
//функция хода компьютера
function zero() {
  let i = Math.round(Math.random() * 8);
  if (o[i]) {
    zero();
  } else {
    document.getElementById(`${i}`).innerHTML = '<img src="Zero.png" width="96px" height="96px">';
    delete map[i];
    o.push(i);
    console.log(map);
    console.log(o);
  }
}
//----------------------------------
//функция хода игрока
function player(argument) {
  if (x[argument]) {
    player(argument);
  } else {
    document.getElementById(`${argument}`).innerHTML = '<img src="Small_cross.png" width="96px" height="96px">';
    delete map[argument];
    x.push(argument);
  }
}

//----------------------------------
//проверка победы

//---------------------------------
//Сам цикл с игрой
zero();
player(argument);
```

```html
<div class="content">
  <div class="tbl">
    <div class="cell" id="0" onclick="player(0)"></div>
    <div class="cell" id="1" onclick="player(1)"></div>
    <div class="cell" id="2" onclick="player(2)"></div>
    <div class="cell" id="3" onclick="player(3)"></div>
    <div class="cell" id="4" onclick="player(4)"></div>
    <div class="cell" id="5" onclick="player(5)"></div>
    <div class="cell" id="6" onclick="player(6)"></div>
    <div class="cell" id="7" onclick="player(7)"></div>
    <div class="cell" id="8" onclick="player(8)"></div>
  </div>

  <div class="linear">
    <img src="Line.png" alt="" class="line1">
    <img src="Line.png" alt="" class="line2">
    <img src="Line.png" alt="" class="line3">
    <img src="Line.png" alt="" class="line4">
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Оформите код в снипет, чтобы можно было воспроизвести ошибку.

Comment: //----------------------------------
//проверка победы
```document.addEventListener("load", () => {
 zero();
 player("2");
})```